# Does field update from approval process on a record causes its trigger to run?

Tags: trigger, approval-process, field-update

I'm getting 101 soql issues from managed pack applications.

There is a configuration on the application that will submit a record for approval at the time of insertion. Logic is hidden.

From the logs I could see before update trigger is getting fired twice. One at the time of insertion(work flow field updates). But other invocation of before update from trigger is something I'm not able to figure out why?

Can someone confirm that field updates from approval will again cause triggers to be invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes at the end of the day its a field update (DML at the backend). Field updates on a specific object from approval will again cause triggers to be invoked if there is a trigger on the object where field update has striked.